# GSON JsonObject "Unsupported Operation Exception: null" getAsString

Tags: scala, playframework, gson

Running a Play! app with Scala. I'm doing a request where the response is expected to be a JSON string. When checking the debugger, the JsonElement returns OK with all information as expected. However, the problem is when I try to actually run methods on that JsonElement.

```
val json = WS.url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?callback=?&sensor=true&address=%s", startAddress+","+startCity+","+startProvince).get.getJson
    val geocoder = json.getAsString
```

The only error I get back is `Unsupported Operation Exception: null` and I've tried this on `getAsString` and `getAsJsonObject` and `getAsJsonPrimitive`

Any idea why it's failing on all methods? Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Maybe your `JsonElement` is a `JsonNull`

What you could do is to first check that it isn't by using  `json.isJsonNull`

Otherwise, try to get its String representation with `json.toString`

Comment: Yep that did the trick, wasn't expecting good ole null. Thanks!

Answer (score 61):

I had a similar problem and I had to change `jsonObject.getAsString()` to `jsonObject.toString();`

Comment: Looking at the github repo, it seems the getAsString() method is not implemented yet. It just throws unsupported exception no matter what. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java

Comment: I believe this is because the getAsString() function is expected to return a sub-property of the root element as a string, not the root element itself. If you have a json such as {"foo":{"bar":"foobar"}} then calling json.get("foo").getAsString() would return the string {"bar":"foobar"}.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I just needed to get the element as an empty string if it is null, so I wrote a function like this:

```
private String getNullAsEmptyString(JsonElement jsonElement) {
        return jsonElement.isJsonNull() ? "" : jsonElement.getAsString();
    }
```

So instead of

```
val geocoder = json.getAsString
```

You can just use this

```
val geocoder = getNullAsEmptyString(json);
```

It returns "" if the element is null and the actual string if it is not

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Henry's answer.  In the spirit of Kotlins "OrNull" Adding an extension function:

```
fun JsonElement.asStringOrNull(): String? {
   return if (isJsonNull) null else asString
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The class `JsonElement` will throw `Unsupported Operation Exception` for any `getAs<Type>` method, because it's an abstract class and makes sense that it is implemented in this way.

For some reason the class `JsonObject`, does not implement the `getAs<Type>` methods, so any call to one of these methods will throw an exception.

Calling the `toString` method on a `JsonElement` object, may solve your issue in certain circumstances, but isn't probably what you want because it returns the json representation as String (e.g. `\"value\"`) in some cases.

I found out that also a `JsonPrimitive` class exists and it does implement the `getAs<Type>` methods. So probably the correct way to proceed is something like this:

```
    String input = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}";
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(input);

    if(jsonTree != null && jsonTree.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();
        value = jsonObject.get("key1").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString()
    }
```

PS. I removed all the nullability mgmt part. If you are coding in Java you probably want to manage this in a better way.

see GitHub source code for `JsonElement`:
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java#L178