# Getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull reports

Tags: java, android

I am getting crash report from some users.Report:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)
at com.impact.ribony.LoginActivity$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java:115)
at com.impact.ribony.LoginActivity$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java:1)
at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:107)
at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:141)
at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:128)
at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonRequestBuilder$1.run(IonRequestBuilder.java:242)
at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncServer.java:53)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
    if (e == null) {
        String anonId=result.get("anonid").getAsString();
     }
}
```

I am sure my `anonid` is not null.Why I am getting this reports ?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324760/gson-jsonobject-unsupported-operation-exception-null-getasstring

Answer (score 8):

This may work for you , Try it once.

```
anonId = result.get("anonid") != JsonNull.INSTANCE ? result.get("anonid").getAsString() : null;
```

or

```
anonId = !result.get("anonid").isJsonNull() ? result.get("anonid").getAsString() : null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (instance instanceof JsonNull) return true
```

Worked for me