# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull

Tags: android, kotlin

When I run this code I get an error: `Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull`. What am I doing wrong?

```kotlin
for (i in 0 until jsonArray!!.size()) {
    val stringCode: JsonObject? = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject()
    singleUpdateArrayList!!.add(
        SingleUpdateResp(
            stringCode!!.get(TagName.AIRWAYBILLNO).getAsString(),
            stringCode.get(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_STATUS).getAsString(),
            stringCode.get(DatabaseHandler.Companion.KEY_SYNC).getAsString()
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616411/15351040

Comment: Before using double exclamation !!  If it won't come as null at the time only you've to use otherwise you've handle null's. first check your json response what are the fields,objects and arrays comes as null then verify not null