# Android - Error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, retrofit

I am trying to use JSON string, Retrofit and other things in my application. But in this particular model something is making my JSON string to be null.

This is the method where I deserialize my string:

```
public static class TaskGSON implements JsonSerializer<Task>, JsonDeserializer<Task>{

    @Override
    public Task deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      System.out.println(json.toString());
      if (!json.isJsonNull()) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Task t = new Task();
        t.mId = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.ID).getAsString();
        t.mProjectId = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.PROJECT_ID).getAsString();
        t.mTitle = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.TITLE).getAsString();
        t.mPriority = Priority.deSerialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.PRIORITY).getAsString());
        t.mCreatedAt = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.CREATED_AT), Date.class);
        t.mCreatedById = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.CREATED_BY_ID).getAsString();
        t.mUpdatedAt = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.UPDATED_AT), Date.class);
        t.mFeedCount = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.FEED_COUNT).getAsInt();
        t.mPermissions = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.PERMISSIONS), new TypeToken<List<Permission>>() {}.getType());

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.COLLECTION_ID)) {
          t.mCollectionId = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.COLLECTION_ID).getAsString();
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.DESCRIPTION)) {
          t.mDescription = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.DESCRIPTION).getAsString();
        }
        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.DUE_DATE) && !jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.DUE_DATE).isJsonNull()) {
          t.mDueDate = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.DUE_DATE), Date.class);
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.COMPLETED_AT)) {
          t.mCompletedAt = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.COMPLETED_AT), Date.class);
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.COMPLETED_BY_ID)) {
          t.mCompletedById = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.COMPLETED_BY_ID).getAsString();
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.DELETED_AT)) {
          t.mDeletedAt = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.DELETED_AT), Date.class);
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.COMPLETED)) {
          t.mCompleted = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.COMPLETED).getAsBoolean();
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.CHECKLIST)) {
          t.mChecklists = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.CHECKLIST), new TypeToken<List<Checklist>>() {}.getType());
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.ATTACHMENTS)) {
          t.mAttachments = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.ATTACHMENTS), new TypeToken<List<Attachment>>() {}.getType());
        }

        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.MARKERS)) {
          t.mMarkers = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.MARKERS), new TypeToken<List<Marker>>() {}.getType());
        }
        if (jsonObject.has(NAMES.Server.CATEGORY_ID)) {
         t.mCategory = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.CATEGORY_ID).getAsString();
        }

        return t;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

So, the problem is that, when I comment the lines of code that check if there's a field "description" and "categoryId" in my JSON string I don't get the error, but if I uncomment these if statements I get the error saying that the Json is null. And I don't know why.

This is the complete logcat:

```
09-22 17:02:57.890 21172-26613/com.construct.test E/AbstractEntitiesViewModel: Error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
   at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)
   at com.construct.v2.models.entities.task.Task$TaskGSON.deserialize(Task.java:740)
   at com.construct.v2.models.entities.task.Task$TaskGSON.deserialize(Task.java:717)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
   at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
   at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:40)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.BodyOnSubscribe.call(BodyOnSubscribe.java:36)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.BodyOnSubscribe.call(BodyOnSubscribe.java:28)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:248)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.fastPath(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:76)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:58)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:32)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:24)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Both fields description and category can be null, but they exist in my Json. It's weird because it works just fine when I comment the lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change from `yourJsonObject.getAsString()` to `yourJsonObject.toString()`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would you mind explaining to me what is the difference?

Comment: I change all the fields from this:
t.mId = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.ID).toString();
to this:
t.mId = jsonObject.get(NAMES.Server.ID).getAsString();
But it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe be your `jsonObject` is a `JsonNull`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27763844/3166697

Comment: But it isn't because I print the Json right in the beginning to the method and it shows all the data.
I print it like this:
System.out.println(json.toString());

Comment: However `UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString` suggests otherwise. Your `jsonObject` at this line is `JsonNull`

Comment: I did this for both fields .isJsonNull() and it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: This is a bad idea. `toString()` is not for this purpose. It will not fail if the json is malformed and an array or an object is in the place where you expect a string. That will lead to hard to trace bugs. What you should do is check specifically `yourJsonObject.isJsonNull()` before `yourJsonObject.getAsString()` and return null.

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer so despite checking that `jsonObject.has(memberName)`, he also needs to check if `jsonObject.get(memberName).isJsonNull()`? How can it be that despite the object having the property, it returns a `JsonNull`? What is the point of testing with `has` then?